# maven build failure on org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc

Tags: java, maven

Please help identify the root cause and possible solutions to this.

Please help me fix the below issue. I have no idea if this is related to java code not supporting that specifi problem any more.

Please see the below CONSOLE output that describes my issue:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc (default) on project library-common-audit-monitor: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc: com/sun/codemodel/CodeWriter
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/jaxb2-maven-plugin/2.3.1/jaxb2-maven-plugin-2.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.11/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/2.2.11/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-jxc/2.2.11/jaxb-jxc-2.2.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M3/qdox-2.0-M3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.3.0/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/aether/aether-util/1.13.1/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.14/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-api/2.5/plexus-compiler-api-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/WKM/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: com.sun.codemodel.CodeWriter
```

Comment: "A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc: com/sun/codemodel/CodeWriter"

Comment: what does that mean.  because the required dependency is in the .m2 repository.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I actually do not remember. I think all i did was manally create the required dependency locaiton in my .m2 home and then it worked.You go and download the pom and jar file from maven central and create the folder structure as per the groupId

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Java 11. Started to work when I reverted back to Java 8.